# Picture in this frame with border radius

Tags: html, css

```css
.a { clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 10% 100%,10% 60%, 0% 50%, 10% 40%); }       
.a { position: relative; width: 500px; height: 500px; background:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/16/07/55/thailand-4852830_960_720.jpg"); border-radius: 15px;
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

I just can do 2 borders.
but I want to 4 borders like this.

[image]

And it can run on IE9 (I know clip-path cant run in IE9)
how to do it without clip-path?

Comment: IE9 ???!!! ... ignore my answer then

Comment: Can you write it without clip-part?

Comment: Honestly, I don't want to waste my time to figure out what kind of properties I can use to make it working on IE9 (I don't even have IE9 to test). Wait for more answers to come but you have to stop using IE9 ...

Comment: Why reformat the code so we have to scroll sideways to see the CSS. There was a reason I clicked TIDY for you

Answer (score 0):

I would add another masking layer in addition to `clip-path` using `mask`

```css
.a {
  --w: 30px; /*wdith of arrow*/
  --r: 25px; /*radius*/
  

  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/16/07/55/thailand-4852830_960_720.jpg");
  border-radius: var(--r); /* Remove this if you want to keep only the left radius */
  padding-left:var(--w);
  clip-path: polygon(var(--w) 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, var(--w) 100%, var(--w) 60%, 0% 50%, var(--w) 40%);
   /* From chrome and webkit browser */
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,transparent 98%,#fff 100%) top    left/var(--r) var(--r) content-box content-box,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    right,transparent 98%,#fff 100%) bottom left/var(--r) var(--r) content-box content-box;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-composite:source-out,source-over;
  /* For firefox and browsers that implement the new mask Specification*/
  mask:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,transparent 98%,#fff 100%) top    left/var(--r) var(--r) content-box content-box,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    right,transparent 98%,#fff 100%) bottom left/var(--r) var(--r) content-box content-box,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask-composite:exclude;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">

</div>
```

Comment: it isn't running in IE 9

Comment: @NguyễnHoàngNamPhương as I commented above ignore my answer ...it won't even run in IE11

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i want it run on ie9